# Map mv command to each row of file and directory names lists

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have two files of file and directory names. I want to map `mv` command from each row of a filenames file to each row in the directory names file. The files are small.

If it helps I have files named sequentially (say f1, f2, f3...f1000). Is there any way to do it in a loop reading one file and one directory?

There can be 3 use cases: One file to many directories, Many files to one directory and many files to many directories (1 file/line = 1 dir/line in my case). My use case pertains to the last one. I have seen `xargs` being used in some of the use cases but I am not sure how to modify for my use case.

Following questions do not help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942422/moving-large-number-of-files

Comment: also asked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/60063312/7552

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
$ head files dirs
==> files <==
foo
bar
baz

==> dirs <==
foodir
bardir
bazdir
```

then using a sufficiently recent version of bash

```
$ while IFS= read -r -u3 f && IFS= read -r -u4 d; do 
    echo mv "$f" "$d/"
  done 3<files 4<dirs
mv foo foodir/
mv bar bardir/
mv baz bazdir/
```

or using GNU `parallel`

```
$ parallel --xapply echo mv {1} {2}/ :::: files :::: dirs
mv foo foodir/
mv bar bardir/
mv baz bazdir/
```